# I have to close the current tab while click on button.window.close(); not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have to close the current tab when clicking on a button. My current code is given below:

```
 function isCloseWindow(){
    window.opener = null;    
    window.open('', '_self', '');  
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: You can only close windows that you've opened

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* close the current window from a script, only those, you have opened. There are some (mostly not working) hacks for this, but they are just that hacks.